# pip install fails when installing mlflow

Tags: pip, mlflow

I'm working on a Window 10 machine and trying to pip install mlflow but I'm getting the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 360, in _error_catcher
yield
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 442, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 447, in read
n = self.readinto(b)
 File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 491, in readinto
n = self.fp.readinto(b)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
....

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

What's this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems due to some bad network setup issues - as you can observe from the fact that you have a socket timeout on what appears to be a pip install.